# Bootstrap twitter 3 - sidebar fixed doesn't scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Demo: http://demo.webtemplum.com

Try to resize to smallest possible your windows, width and height. Try also with "flickr demo page", to have main window more long as possible.

You will note that sidebar (collapse in small screen but reopening with button) doesn't scroll with page. Also, under that div (#sidebar-wrapper), with height of 100%, when you scroll, you'll note the white of page.

How i can solve that problems? Thank you very much

EDIT: Look at the image:[image: sidebar problem]

1) Black rectangle: when top sidebar scroll, it leaves white page
2) Red rectangle: when sidebar is more long than window, simply it is "covered", you cannot click on others menu

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want it to scroll with the page?

Comment: Not only. I've edited with a picture to explain best my requests. Thak you!

Comment: In firefox the menu scroll with the page. About the "page white" the #sidebar-wrapper has postion:fixed but have no top defined. you will have the top set to 0 after scrolling the height of your fixed navbar (50px). Use the affix plugin to do this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 1):

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Make position:absolute which will solve the issue for black rectangle area.